# Arreglo con NestJS MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo un problema al momento de ingresar este json a mongoDB por medio de NestJS

```
{
    "nompro": "Rapibrot",
    "despro": "Regulador de Crecimiento de plantas",
    "prepro": 40.20,
    "tipo": "Quemante",
    "componente": [
        {
            "nombre": "Hydrogen Cyanamide",
            "porcentaje": "500 G/L"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Aditivos",
            "porcentaje": "c.s.p.1L"
        }
    ]

}
```

Lo guarda asi

```
"data": {
        "_id": "5f3dd7c3b0fa5324a0efaa85",
        "nompro": "Rapibrot",
        "despro": "Regulador de Crecimiento de plantas",
        "prepro": 40.2,
        "tipo": "Quemante",
        "componente": [
            {
                "_id": "5f3dd7c3b0fa5324a0efaa86",
                "nombre": "Hydrogen Cyanamide",
                "porcentaje": "500 G/L"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f3dd7c3b0fa5324a0efaa87",
                "nombre": "Aditivos",
                "porcentaje": "c.s.p.1L"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Y en el arreglo lo guarda con un id cada uno de los datos y eso es lo que no quiero
¿Como evitaria guardar ese arreglo sin que se genere un id por dato?

Comment: Dices: *Tengo un problema al momento de ingresar este json a mongoDB por medio de NestJS*, ¿podrías mostrar cómo lo *ingresas*? Ya sabemos que tienes un JSON y sabemos el resultado obtenido, pero falta ver el código de cómo lo haces. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta y agregar lo que hace falta. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id) de Mongoose , guarda "_id" en sus objetos por defecto. Entiendo que tendrías de cambiar el Schema que utilizas para el objeto en cuestión. No obstante, personalmente no recomiendo desactivar _id, ya que es un valor insignificante y a veces muy útil.

Aun así, si quieres desactivarlo aquí tienes un ejemplo, de como:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const ComponenteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  "nombre": {type:String},
  "porcentaje": {type:String}
},{_id:false})


const MainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "nompo":{type:String},
    "despro": {type:String},
    "prepro": {type:Number},
    "tipo": {type:String}, 
    "componente":[ComponenteSchema]
    })
```